# AngularJS undefined, null and 0

Tags: angularjs

Consider the following code:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
    <div ng-show="someVariable.someProperty">Value of someProperty is set</div>
</div>
```

Now, when I set in my `SomeCtrl` controller:

```
$scope.someVariable.someProperty = 1;
```

It will show the div, as expected. But when I set:

```
$scope.someVariable.someProperty = 0;
```

It does not, while I only want to hide it in case `$scope.someVariable.someProperty` is either `undefined` or `null`. Of course I could write a simple Javascript helper-function to give me the expected result, or write something like:

```
<div ng-show="someVariable.someProperty || someVariable.someProperty == 0">Value of someProperty is set</div>
```

But isn't there a more elegant way to 
handle this in AngularJS?

Comment: `0` in JavaScript is falsy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I only want to hide it in case $scope.someVariable.someProperty is either undefined or null

In JavaScript, undefined == null, but neither == 0. No need for extra functions or an extra conditional
`ng-show="someVariable.someProperty != null"`

Comment: You might be worried about using `==`, since people always talk about how it breaks stuff. But this is actually the one and only case that you can use it; most js linters will flag `==` unless it's checking null.

Answer (score 0):

Change your logic to be something more like this then:

```
ng-show="someVariable.someProperty !== null && someVariable.someProperty >= 0">
```

That way `null` or `undefined` will be falsy.

I almost forgot that `null >= 0 === true` (silly Javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

Put a function in the controller like this:

```
$scope.shouldShow = function() {
   if($scope.someVariable.someProperty === null || 
      $scope.someVariable.someProperty === "undefined") {
      return false;
   }
   return true;

}
```

and in the html:

```
<div ng-show="shouldShow()">Value of someProperty is set</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @tymeJV, "0" is evaluated as false in JS, so ng-show="0" will evaluate to hiding the div.

In SomeCtrl, you could write a function which encapsulates the logic to determine whether someProperty is null or undefined and return true or false based on that evaluation.

```
angular.module("app")
.controller("SomeCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.someVariable = {};
    $scope.someVariable.someProperty = null;
    $scope.isNullorUndefined = function(value) {
        return value === null || angular.isUndefined(value);         
    };
});

<div ng-show="!isNullOrUndefined(someVariable.someProperty)">Value of someProperty is set</div>
```